# Chrome driver not working when extracting electron package using --asar

Tags: javascript, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver, electron-packager

I am using electron for writing a desktop application using visual studio code and I have **chromedriver** included in my application

When I using the following command `electron-packager .` for extracting electron package , the output is uncompressed files and in this case **chromedriver** is working normally

But when using the following command `electron-packager . --asar`, the output is a compressed package and in this case **chromdriver** is not working as expected and  I am getting the following error when running my application

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554634/child-process-fork-not-starting-an-express-server-inside-of-packaged-electron-ap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of running a compressed package, code is not able to find chromedriver.exe file

For solving this, I added chromedriver.exe file to a folder and pointed to its path in the code In case of running a compressed package, code is not able to find chromedriver.exe file

[Chromedriver.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2dSz.png)